# Игра Города, почему не работает код?

Tags: python

```
import random

cityList = []
usedcityList = []
intermediatedict = []
userCityInput = ''
counter = 0

with open('citylist.txt','r') as fileCL:
    textCityList = fileCL.readlines()
    for textCL in textCityList:
        textCL = textCL.strip()
        cityList.append(textCL)


def checkforamatch(arguserCityInput):

    for xcityList in cityList:
        if xcityList == arguserCityInput:
            global counter
            counter += 1
            for xusedcityList in usedcityList:
                if xusedcityList == xcityList:
                    counter = 0
                    return 1
            counter = 0
            usedcityList.append(arguserCityInput)
            return 0
        if counter > 0:
            return -1

def lastleter(arguserCityInput):
    return arguserCityInput[-1:]

def findword(letter):
    for xcityList in cityList:
        if letter == xcityList[0]:
            intermediatedict.append(xcityList)
    randomWord = random.randrange(0,(len(intermediatedict)-1))
    for xusedcityList in usedcityList:
        if xusedcityList == cityList[randomWord]:
            findword(letter)
        else:
            intermediatedict.clear()
            usedcityList.append(cityList[randomWord])
            return cityList[randomWord]
while True:
    print('Введите город:')
    userCityInput = input()
    result = checkforamatch(userCityInput)
    if result == 1:
        print('\nГород уже был использован в Игре.')
    if result == 0:
        resultlast = lastleter(userCityInput)
        resultlast = findword(resultlast)
        print(resultlast)
    if result == -1:
        print('\nТакого города не существет.')
```

Решил реализовать игру города, вопрос такой, почему в функции findword не добавляется слово в промежуточный список intermediatedict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно сделать короче

```
def recursive_input_city(city_dict: dict, city_last='', player=0) -> None:
    city = input('Player_{} Введите город: '.format(int(player))).strip().lower()  # ввод города
    if city:  # выход
        if city_last and city[0] != city_last[-1]:
            print('Город должен начинатся с последней буквы предыдущего {}"{}" -> "{}"{}'.format(
                city_last[:-1], city_last[-1], city[0], city[1:]))
        else:
            check = city_dict.get(city)  # проверка города на существование
            if check:  # город найден
                city_last = city
                city_dict[city] = False  # пометить город использованным
                player = not player  # сменить игрока
            elif check is None:
                print('Такого города не существет.')
            else:
                print('Город уже был использован в Игре.')
        recursive_input_city(city_dict, city_last, player)  # рекурсия

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('citylist.txt') as file:
        lines = filter(bool, map(str.strip, file))  # исключить пустые строки
        cities = {}.fromkeys(map(str.lower, lines), True)  # {'aqwea': True, 'aasda': True, }
    recursive_input_city(cities)  # старт
```

out:

```
Player_0 Введите город: qwe
Такого города не существет.
Player_0 Введите город: aqwea
Player_1 Введите город: aqwea
Город уже был использован в Игре.
Player_1 Введите город: basdb
Город должен наченаися с последней буквы предыдущего aqwe"a" -> "b"asdb
Player_1 Введите город: aasda
Player_0 Введите город: azxca
Player_1 Введите город:
```

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема была в регистре букв, если кому интересно, и первую функцию можно реализовать без счетчика.

Answer (score 0):

А в чём проблема собственно, может просто сделать другой код по типу этого?

```
 import random
 import time
 while True:
     str=input()
     test_list=['Арзамас','Анапа','Москва','Самара']
     lister=list(str)
     check=lister[-1]
     res = [idx for idx in test_list if idx[0].lower() == check.lower()]
     prers=random.choice(res)
     trr=lister[-1]
     rers=list(prers)
     print(prers)
     res = [idx for idx in test_list if idx[0].lower() == check.lower()]
     time.sleep(0.1)
     res = [idx for idx in test_list if idx[0].lower() == check.lower()]
```